# How long will it take until a video sitemap is indexed?

Tags: video, indexing, sitemap, google-search-console

A few days ago(2/3), I submitted about 10.000 videos, and about 7000 news items. Now, most of the news-items are indexed, but unfortunately none of the video-items. According to "Webmaster Help Tools" the video site-map is approved.

Can someone tell me how long it will take before my video's are visible at Google?

http://i52.tinypic.com/9t1rgm.jpg

http://i53.tinypic.com/x6gbph.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well to that question

> Can someone tell me how long it will take before my video's are visible at Google?

this question is a little bit tricky .... yes, the google engineer in charge of  video sitemaps could probably tell you (after some checking with internal google tools) how long it would take, but any other mortal -> no.

to many factors (how old, important, trusted is your site?,  what videos? what vertical? how fast is your server? where are the videos hosted?)

but well, i submitted a video sitemap, 3 days later i got the first google referred visit due to a SERP where my video showed up. i have strong indication that google discovered that specific video due to my video sitemap.